# crop image with Aspect ratio and blank space

Tags: android, imageview, crop

i want a crop library that let user to crop image only if match width or match height also (2) :
[image]

also.

Answer (score 2):

You should try [this](https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper). It is Powerful (Zoom, Rotation, Multi-Source), customizable (Shape, Limits, Style), optimized (Async, Sampling, Matrix) and simple image cropping library for Android.

Hope this solves your problem

Comment: this is very power full, nut i cant, crop with blank space